# Run-time error'7': Out of Memory when moving columns

Tags: vba, excel

thanks in advance for any and all help. What this part of my macro is supposed to do is to move some "key" columns over. I tried to accomplish this in the least memory intensive way possible. Instead of cutting the columns and inserting them, I did the following. Why am I running into a ridiculous out of memory error, then? It's not even a lot of data. Excel is capping out at around 3.3GB of memory usage right now.

Any suggestions for cleaning up my code?

```
'Moves Critical Columns'
Sheets("A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("H").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("H").Value = Columns("X").Value
Columns("X").Delete

Sheets("B").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("H").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("H").Value = Columns("X").Value
Columns("X").Delete

Sheets("C").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("AA").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("Z").Value
Columns("Z").Delete
Columns("Z").Delete

Sheets("D").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("AA").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("Z").Value
Columns("Z").Delete
Columns("Z").Delete

Sheets("E").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("AG").Value
Columns("AG").Delete

Sheets("F").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("AG").Value
Columns("AG").Delete

Sheets("G").Select
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("AT").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("AU").Value
Columns("AU").Delete
Columns("AU").Delete

Sheets("H").Select
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("AT").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("AU").Value
Columns("AU").Delete
Columns("AU").Delete

Sheets("I").Select
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("T").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("BT").Value
Columns("G").Value = Columns("BU").Value
Columns("BU").Delete
Columns("BU").Delete
Columns("BU").Delete

Sheets("J").Select
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("T").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("BT").Value
Columns("G").Value = Columns("BU").Value
Columns("BU").Delete
Columns("BU").Delete
Columns("BU").Delete

Sheets("K").Select
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Insert XlDirection.xlToRight
Columns("E").Value = Columns("BS").Value
Columns("F").Value = Columns("BA").Value
Columns("BA").Delete
Columns("BA").Delete
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that although you may not have much data, you are still running the operations on the entire column. That gets expensive quickly. I would use arrays. Read the table of data you want to move (`source`) to an array, `dim` another array (`target`) with the number of rows (can make it dynamic if you need to) and columns (sounds like it would be static in your case) and move the data from `source` to `target` as you desire. Then you can output `target` to another worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The line `DoEVENTS` might help - putting this in an array and running DoEvents would work or putting it between every column or something.

Putting it in easy terms it allows the operating system to do its job in between your code running - I've found inserting it in longer or heavier running codes tends to help with out of memory errors.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264522.aspx for more information on DoEvents

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will eliminate the memory problem you're having because I could not reproduce it and it might be due to something in your environment. However, try to limit your work to the `UsedRange`, and use the "Cut-Insert" technique instead of `copy/insert/paste/delete`.

This is what is done in the routine `moveColumn` in the code below. It is always good to factorize the common task and simplify the code. Notice that `moveColumn` can be used for moving multiple neighbor columns simultaneously; but not if their order will change, in which case you need to move them one by one (start with the one that will be moved to the leftmost position).

Finally, there's no need to `Select` anything during the code execution, which is a source of trouble as well. With all this in mind, your code can be written as below:

```
Sub MoveCriticalColumns()
  moveColumn Sheets("A"), "X", "H"
  moveColumn Sheets("B"), "X", "H"

  moveColumn Sheets("C"), "AA", "E"
  moveColumn Sheets("C"), "Z", "F"

  moveColumn Sheets("D"), "AA", "E"
  moveColumn Sheets("D"), "Z", "F"

  moveColumn Sheets("E"), "AG", "E"
  moveColumn Sheets("F"), "AG", "E"

  moveColumn Sheets("G"), "AT:AU", "E:F" ' in one operation
  moveColumn Sheets("H"), "AT:AU", "E:F" ' in one operation

  moveColumn Sheets("I"), "T", "E"
  moveColumn Sheets("I"), "BT:BU", "F:G" ' in one operation

  moveColumn Sheets("J"), "T", "E"
  moveColumn Sheets("I"), "BT:BU", "F:G" ' in one operation

  moveColumn Sheets("K"), "BS", "E"
  moveColumn Sheets("K"), "BA", "F"
End Sub

Sub moveColumn(sh As Worksheet, oldPosition As String, newPosition As String)
  With sh.UsedRange
    .Columns(oldPosition).Cut
    .Columns(newPosition).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That parameter appears to be irrelevant here (removed) because the moved column will be inserted with its format.

Comment: Hmm. @A.S.H - this advice seems very promising, but I'm getting an "insert method of range class failed" error pointing to the line `.Columns(newPosition).Insert Shift:=xlToRight`.

Comment: @KevinNocom it is working for me flawlessly. Is there something special in your data, such as formulas, data validation, etc?

Comment: Not at all. It's all just values actually.

Answer (score 0):

Cut and Insert, as suggested in the solution offered by @A.S.H. is very efficient because it doesn't copy formats. Instead, it uses formats found at the destination, either from the right or left of the inserted columns. If this is an issue, meaning the cell formats must be copied from the source, the following code offers an alternative.

```
Sub MoveColumn(Ws As Worksheet, _
               Targets As String, _
               Sources As String)
    ' insert columns specified by "Targets"
    ' copy contents of "Sources" to the inserted columns
    ' and delete the "Sources" columns

    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Dim ClmCount As Integer

    With Ws.UsedRange
        Set SourceRange = .Columns(Sources)
        Set TargetRange = .Columns(Targets)
        ClmCount = TargetRange.Columns.Count
        If ClmCount < SourceRange.Columns.Count Then
            MsgBox "The number of columns specified as 'Source'" & vbCr & _
                   "exceeds the available space in the specified" & vbCr & _
                   "'Target' range.", vbCritical, "Invalid specification"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Columns(Targets).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Set TargetRange = .Cells(1, TargetRange.Column - ClmCount)
        SourceRange.Copy
        TargetRange.PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        SourceRange.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

This sub can handle a single column or any number of adjacent columns. This is an example of the code which would replace the first batch of column moves in your original code. Note that the use of `ActiveSheet` is dangerous (your original code does this) because it is easy to forget which sheet is active while looking at the code.

Private Sub TestMove()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        MoveColumn ActiveSheet, "E:F", "AT:AU"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

The second batch needs two calls of the procedure because the columns are not contiguous. After adding this batch to the calling procedure it would look like this:-

```
Private Sub TestMove()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        MoveColumn ActiveSheet, "E:F", "AT:AU"
        MoveColumn Sheets("I"), "E:F", "BT:BU"
        MoveColumn Sheets("I"), "E", "T"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```